# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' (JS -- OnClick event)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

There's a ton of questions titled the same and I can't find any that have the issue in the place I do.

What I'm going for:
Div that's clicked, and changes another div.

Code:

```js
function divOne_Click() {
  var x = document.getElementById("divMenuOne");
  if (x.style.display == "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```
            <div class="MobileContentTitle" onclick="divOne_Click()">
            <p style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; color: #FFFFFF;">Box One Title</p>
        </div>
        <div class="MobileContentMenu" id="divMenuOne" runat="server">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rpt_menu_1" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table id="tbl_menu" align="center" >
                    <tr class="MenuTR">
                        <td><asp:Label ID="lbl_menuItemDescHead" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="lbl_menuPriceHead" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
                    </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr class="MenuTR">
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_menuitem" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("MenuItemDesc") %>' CssClass="MenuDesc"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_menuprice" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("MenuItemPrice", "{0:C}") %>' CssClass="MenuPrice"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate></table></FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
     </div>
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong..

Comment: My thought's as well, nothing happens in Edge (not that it matters), Chrome or Firefox. Debug code just pops up on click.

I did remove the css style from the element thinking this caused in issue, but the same error happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to be certain based on the snippet provided from the .aspx page, but it is probable that the ID of `divMenuOne` is changing by the time it is displayed in the browser, because of `runat="server"`. Elements coming from the server may have their client-side IDs change, especially when they are inside another control such as a repeater or a user control.

In this case I would recommend selecting the element by its class instead of its ID.

Comment: Good call sir. Totally slipped my mind and wasn't paying attention to that. Thanks!